# Why do i keep getting an error when running rake db:migrate on my fresh rails instance?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Why do I keep getting the error seen below when running `rake db:migrate`...

[image: SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")/cygdrive/c/users/daniel/workspace/ruby/rails/tesT_app/db/migrate/20130606041329_devise_create_users.rb:40:in `change']

I've followed to the letter https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started  on the devise github readme, created a brand new project, and still get the error.

**Created a new rail app**:  (*success*)
[image: rails new tesT_app]

**Added `gem 'devise'` to my Gemfile**: (*success*)
[image: gem 'devise']

**Installed the bundle**: (*success*)
[image: bundle install]

**Ran the rails generator**:  (*success*)
[image: rails generate devise:install]

**Generated a devise model with the name User**: (*success*)
[image: rails generate devise User]

I referred to the SO question at [SQLite3:CantOpenException (uanble to open database file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454089/sqlite3cantopenexception-uanble-to-open-database-file)   which lead me to try using `rake db:create` which returned `db/development.sqlite3 already exists`. fine.

**I then ran `rake db:migrate` per the getting started..**: (*fail*)
With the error `SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")/cygdrive/c/users/daniel/workspace/ruby/rails/tesT_app/db/migrate/20130606041329_devise_create_users.rb:40:in`change'`

What is happening?  I am following this getting started to the letter, and cannot figure this out!

I'd really appreciate it.

**edit**: Line :40 on ...create_users.rb is
`add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true`

and note that i hadn't touched anything.

Comment: it works for a standard rails object, but only complains with devise.. don't know if perms would be the issue? *edit* perms are fine

Comment: Could you post a copy of you migration file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite, index name uniqueness is enforced at the database level. In MySQL you will not reproduce same issue. You can eather change index name or comment this line out (and return while deploing in production), or change database (I mean use mysql instead).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I havn't done much with sqlite so my ignorance might be getting the best of me.  if what you say is true, it'd make sense why it wasn't working.  I'll let you know when I get home

Comment: so - it worked just fine when i commented out the indexes - and works just fine.   Could you possibly link me the documentation that makes what you say, correct?  Link me where it says "sqlite uses a mandatory index" etc.. i'd really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I thought you had a separated user model.
Could you please post your migration file ?
Also please try running

```
rake db:drop
```

(to delete your current db) then

```
rake db:create and rake db:migrate
```

That will make sure you're migrating on a brand new db.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I will attempt this when I get home today

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I would suggest following this way. Do the migration in two steps: For example, let's say you have a migration called users. Migrate this normally as you would, but here don't enforce the uniqueness yet:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create table :users do |t|
      t.integer :name
      t.integer :email
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Migrate by using:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

After migration, create another migration:

```
$ rails generate migration add_index_users_name_email
```

In this migration file, add the uniqueness:

```
class AddIndexUsersNameEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :name, unique: true
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Migrate as usual and this should work and won't throw the errors because as Ivan mentioned SQLite enforces uniqueness at the db level and doing it in this way will solve the issue.

Another way to solve this if that is still throwing errors is to create a separate migration for each entry. For example:

```
$ rails generate migration add_index_users_name
$ rails generate migration add_index_users_email

class AddIndexUsersName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :name, unique: true
  end
end

class AddIndexUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Let me know if it solves your problem